# How do I find the smallest number in a given row?

Tags: math, recursion, conditional-statements

I need to find the first number in any of the rows as shown on this: (http://puu.sh/rbVEJ/10a2086c82.png). I got it to work for only rowStart(6); but for nothing else. Can anyone help?

```
class ShelfRows{

  public static void main (String[] args){
    rowStart(6); // ans = 16
    rowStart(10); // ans = 46

}

  public static int rowStart(int row){
    int n = row - 1;
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    return n*2 + rowStart(n);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *row starting number* is count of *squares* in all the rows below. One can easily see that they are organized in triangle. Space taken by triangle is half of space taken by a rectangle. The exact formula for your example is:

```
public static int rowStart(int row){
  return (row * (row - 1))/2;
}
```

the `row - 1` vs `row` is to account for the diagonal squares. Instead of being "split" (to create a proper triangle) they add `row/2` of squares to the smooth triangle. (Hope it can be understood...).

Answer (score 0):

Read about trianglular numbers.

```
 smallest_in_n-th_row = n*(n-1)+1
```